# Adjoint representation is completely reducible

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra. Let $Ad$ be the adjoin representation of $L$. If $Ad$ is completely reducible, then
$$Ad(L)\cong L/Z(L) \cong L_1 \oplus \dots \oplus L_t$$
Now from this I think it's clear than $L$ it's completely reducible. So if $I$ is an ideal of $L$, then exists $J$ ideal of $L$ such that
$$L=I \oplus J$$
For me this is clear from a "logical point of view" but I don't find a way to prove this in a formal way. some ideas?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2684725/submodules-of-completely-reducible-modules?rq=1). Ideals are submodules of $L$ - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183540/show-that-submodules-of-l-are-precisely-the-ideals-of-l). Your question seems related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205378/if-a-lie-algebra-l-is-a-completely-reducible-mathrmad-l-module-then-l).